# get values from impex into InitDefaultInterceptor Hybris

Tags: java, interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an impex file(example)

```
INSERT_UPDATE Subscriber;firstName[unique=false];lastName[unique=false];email[unique=true];bulk(code)[default=false]
;FirstName;lastName;email@gmail.com;true;
```

and an InitDefaultInterceptor

```
 public class MyInterceptor implement InitDefaultInterceptor<SubscriberModel>{

onInitDefaults(SubscriberModel model, InterceptorContext ctx)
}
```

How can I get values from the impex in this interceptor? I try to use

```
model.getFirstName(); 
....
```

but all the methods returns "null". What can I do to get the values ? I need to implement a logic before I save them into db.

Comment: What is your usecase ,I mean to say what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I say the ideea as comment in Yoni answer. Can you sir have a suggest for my current problem? Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make use of the values that are being sent, you need to use a `PrepareInterceptor` instead of a `InitDefaultInterceptor` interceptor.

- `InitDefaultInterceptor` : The Init Defaults Interceptor is called when a model is filled with its default values. In your case, this happens at creation of the new instance of the object you want to add to the database. This interceptor is used to add **default** values (next to the ones you already defined in your items.xml). Only the defaults, marked in your items.xml are inserted at this point. **No data from your impex is loaded here**, as this just handles the defaults for new objects, no matter the content that will be added at a later stage.
- `PrepareInterceptor` : The Prepare Interceptor is called before a model is saved to the database. Use this to add values to the model or modify existing ones before they are saved. In this interceptor, the values of your impex will be filled in the model object. You can add or modify your data here depending on your usecase.

For more info on all type of interceptors, there is a [help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/aa417173fe4a4ba5a473c93eb730a417/v2005/en-US/8bfbf43e8669101480d0f060d79b1baa.html) page from SAP that describes all of them.

Comment: I did what you say and work except the fact I have a problem. So I have the Prepare Interceptor where I pass to an service the model. There I fill some fields, and one of them is boolean. The boolean need to be false after the logic is complete, from the impex he comes true. So what is happen is: The Prepare interceptor pass the model,  in service the method receive the model, set some values and is called method "modelService.save(object)".

Comment: After this is returned to the prepare interceptor with that boolean false. After this is going in validate interceptor and after again in prepare interceptor where the boolean is again true and is needed to repeat again this step to stay false. What can I do to remain the boolean false without repeating the step again?

Comment: Thank's a lot for the explanation!

Comment: The problem is your service. that should not call modelService.save(Object) because you are in the process of saving your object at the moment. The prepare interceptor is triggered when a save is called. So in your case => Prepare interceptor => call service => calls save => calls Prepare interceptor => (might call save again? and cause some kind of loop) => rest of prepare/validation interceptors

Comment: I put modelService.save() because in my mind I think it needs to save the model after I update him, but I remove the line and now all works great. Thank you so much for your time and good explanation!! Have a nice day, and thank you again!